# SAS - adding linear constraint to coefficients on large number of dummies

Tags: sas, restriction

I am running a regression on various groups of dummies: schools, subjects (English, Maths, History..), level (A, B, C).

The data is formed as follows:

```
School  Subject     Level
XYZ     English      A
XYZ     English      B
ZYD     History      A
DCA     Maths        C
```

I am running proc glm on the data:

```
proc glm data=sample;
class school subject level;
model Y= school subject level/solution;
run;
```

But I would like to put a linear restriction on the coefficients on each group of dummies:

i.e.

1. I would like to force the coefficients on all the school dummies to sum up to zero.
2. I would like to force the coefficients on all the level dummies to also sum up to zero.
3. I would like to force the coefficients on all the subject dummies to sum up to zero.

I know in proc reg I can use the restrict statement. But the problem is that there are hundreds of school dummies.

How do I do this in GLM? Or is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: sorry just realized the data format is off. The data format is as follows: